# Is there an expression describing some thing precious because it's rare?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

This is a question similar to [A word to describe something that is desired only because it is rare](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/323985/80007), but I am looking for an expression, a saying, or an idiom use in daily life, not a term or jargon.

I'm also err on the side of natural (not artificial) rareness, and the thing is truly valuable. Something like "diamond is precious because it's rare".

Comment: Diamonds are precious because De Beers has a near monopoly and does a lot of marketing to make people want diamonds... they're not as rare as people think. Your example is quite literally exactly the opposite of what you want it to mean.

Comment: There's expressions like: "You should hold on to that one. < *some noun* > s like that don't come along that often."

Comment: Nothing is precious simply because it is rare.  For example, a punch in the nose is exceedingly rare for me, and I have no desire whatever to obtain one.  A thing that is desirable for some other reason may be more so to some people if it is difficult to obtain, but that's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**precious few** ; **precious little***

Its colloquial usage is merely to describe something that there is very little of, but that doesn't mean it hasn't been used in contexts of something actually being *precious* just through its *rarity*. Such examples are outlined here:

[Sermons, homiletical expositions, and leading thoughts on texts of Scripture](https://books.google.com/books?id=WvgEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA494&dq=%22precious+few%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKjeXo_fXNAhWMQD4KHSChB2gQ6AEINjAF#v=onepage&q=%22precious%20few%22&f=false)

> "Although they have been but a few, yet, a **precious few**."

[Life Lessons: Train of Thought](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rf4niOcCZvYC&pg=RA1-PA31&dq=%22precious+few%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTvL2p_vXNAhXLND4KHfx0C1I4FBDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22precious%20few%22&f=false)

> "Enjoy those **precious few moments** in time you get with your loved ones — that half hour of helping with homework, that hour at the pizza parlor, and even those two hours at the movie theater."

[Marnie's Christmas Wish](https://books.google.com/books?id=zK97AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22precious+few%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMvtvH_vXNAhWBaT4KHZCSCIc4KBDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%22precious%20few%22&f=false)

> "Loss and trials change us in ways that we can't imagine are for our own good until after we have gone through the fires of mourning, but then we come out with a greater appreciation for the living amongst us, and the **precious few days** we get to spend with them."

[31 SINS: AN ANTHOLOGY](https://books.google.com/books?id=B011BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22precious+few%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMvtvH_vXNAhWBaT4KHZCSCIc4KBDoAQhLMAg#v=onepage&q=%22precious%20few%22&f=false)

> The feeling was difficult to contain as he neared the conclusion that he was living his last few moments on this planet, inhaling those **precious few breaths** allotted to him."

---

...And hundreds of other instances [can be found on Google Books:](https://www.google.com/search?q=precious+few+moments&oq=precious+few+moments&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1972j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22precious+few%22&tbm=bks&start=90)

--[Used to describe endangered species:](https://www.google.com/search?q=precious+few+moments&oq=precious+few+moments&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1972j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22precious+few+species%22)

--[Used to describe rare jewels:](https://www.google.com/search?q=precious+few+moments&oq=precious+few+moments&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1972j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22precious+few+jewels%22)

--[Used to describe rare/unique moments:](https://www.google.com/search?q=precious+few+moments&oq=precious+few+moments&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1972j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22precious+few+moments%22)

---

*(btw, **precious few** should be preferred over **precious little** in this particular usage because **little** will make the reader misread the object in question as *small*, and not *rare*.)

The connotative advantage of *few* in its relation to *precious* is that *few* usually means only a handful, or from any small number above two. For this reason, *few* connotes a greater rarity than even *rare* itself does. For example, a *rare* species could number anywhere from the hundreds to the thousands, but a species that there is *few of* would only number from the tens to the hundreds, which makes its use an example of *litotes*, or understatement/underestimate for persuasive effect.

Comment: can I use *precious rare*?

Comment: @Ooker ~ 
You can, but "*precious rare*" isn't as idiomatic/colloquial as "*precious few*". That is to say, people will understand you if you use it, but the appeal of *precious few* lies in its evocative and emotive force for native speakers that have often heard the phrase.

Comment: Besides, the rarity of the object in question will be implied through the use of few. And I think even more so because *few* has a connotation of higher rarity than even *rare* does, in my opinion. *Few* usually means a handful only. *Rare* can mean more than that. For example a species numbering in the thousands is rare. But a species numbering in the hundreds would be *few*.

Comment: I see. So *rare* is used when comparing to the whole, while *few* is used for a counting

Answer (score 2):

You appear to refer to economic concept of the ***[scarcity principle](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/scarcity-principle.html)***:

> - An economic theory which states that limited supply, combined with high demand, equals a lack of pricing equilibrium. Typically, demand and supply will gravitate prices to a stable balance; however, scarcity of a good or service changes the way buyers will value the purchase, thus leading to new market conditions.

Comment: *dearth* :  "scarcity that makes dear; specifically :  famine" –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dearth). "Middle English *derthe* (originally in the sense ‘shortage and dearness of food’)" –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dearth&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 2):

*Diamonds don't grow on trees.*

**not grow on trees**

> in. not to be abundant; not to be wasted. (Usually said about money.) *Don’t waste the glue. That stuff doesn’t grow on trees, you know.* — [McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions Copyright © 2006](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+grow+on+trees)

Answer (score 2):

**Absence makes the heart grow fonder.**

> Meaning: The lack of something increases the desire for it. –[phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/absence-makes-the-heart-grow-fonder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Rosalind Fergusson, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs* (1983) identifies a proverb that is exactly on point, but it is expressed so flatly that it has very little charm:

> That thing which is rare is dear.

Prosaic though the expression may be, Robert Dent, [*Shakespeare's Proverbial Language: An Index*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tZYW8gyI2bYC&pg=PA228&dq=%22That+thing+which+is+rare+is+dear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6zYKA6dHOAhVN9WMKHWwXDysQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22That%20thing%20which%20is%20rare%20is%20dear%22&f=false) (1981) traces it back to the year 1606.

A somewhat livelier version of the same idea appears in Wolfgang Mieder, [Dictionary of American Proverbs](https://books.google.com/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&pg=PA937&dq=%22want+that+makes+its+value%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPhbOk39HOAhUW1GMKHZ1bBoIQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22want%20that%20makes%20its%20value%22&f=false) (1992):

> It's not the worth of a thing but the want that makes its value.

Mieder notes that this proverb is recorded in [Word-book of Virginia Folk-speech](https://books.google.com/books?id=KmYPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22not+the+worth+of+a+thing+but+the+want%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj28Nfb3tHOAhUUSGMKHWoWB4kQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22not%20the%20worth%20of%20a%20thing%20but%20the%20want%22&f=false) (1912—but also reports that the proverb's origin goes back to Thomas Draxe, [*Bibliotheca Scholastica Instructissima. Or, a Treasurie of Ancient Adagies, and Sententious Prouerbes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mYlAnQEACAAJ&dq=%22Draxe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj31q6w3dHOAhVD1WMKHallAzwQ6AEIYzAK) (1616). Unfortunately none of the three copies of Draxe in Google Books are searchable, even for snippet views if text.

The converse of the proverb cited by Fergusson appears in George Apperson & Martin Manser, [*Dictionary of Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7PMZJqSR4sAC&pg=PA113&dq=%22What+costs+little,+is+less+esteemed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz5J6S8tHOAhUH-mMKHX2gAS0Q6AEINjAF#v=onepage&q=%22What%20costs%20little%2C%20is%20less%20esteemed%22&f=false) (2007):

> What costs little is little esteemed.

Apperson & Manser reports that this phrase first appeared in English in a 1612 translation of *Don Quixote*.

Charles Spurgeon, [*The Salt Cellars*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W1dWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT479&dq=%22rare+birds+are+sure+to+be+noticed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLrbmk59HOAhVH3mMKHYFNBK4Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22rare%20birds%20are%20sure%20to%20be%20noticed%22&f=false), volume 2 (1889) offers this adage, followed by his interpretation of it:

> Rare birds are sure to be noticed.
>
> *More was at first made of a black swan than of all the royal birds on the Thames. Something eccentric and out of the common soon commands attention; yet wise men value not things by their rarity but by their real worth.*

Another Spurgeon proverb applies the notion of valuing what is rare to human company:

> Who comes seldom is welcome.
>
> *A warning against wearing out your welcome by making yourself too common. People value you the more for being scarce.*